# MySQL inner join where table2 child_id is like table2 id

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and as the title says I need something like a double inner join no. I have no idea if that works but I believe there should be an easy way.

What I've got is this statement which works fine:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id img_id, t1.nav_id img_nav_id, t1.name img_name, t1.img_title img_title, t1.img_text img_text,
    t2.id nav_id,t2.parent_id nav_parent_id, t2.name nav_name, t2.directlink nav_directlink
FROM images t1
INNER JOIN navigation t2
ON t2.id=t1.nav_id 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,101
```

now t2 (navigation table) looks like this

```
+----+-----------+------------------+------------------+------+
| id | parent_id | name             | directlink       | rang |
+----+-----------+------------------+------------------+------+
|  1 |         0 | Home             | home             |    0 |
|  3 |         0 | Architektur      | architektur      |    1 |
|  7 |         0 | Design           | design           |    2 |
|  8 |         0 | Contact          | contact          |    3 |
| 11 |         3 | Surfabricaziun 5 | surfabricaziun_5 |    0 |
| 12 |         7 | Fluor            | fluor            |    1 |
| 13 |         7 | Maisa            | maisa            |    2 |
| 14 |         3 | Fuldera          | fuldera          |    3 |
```

and t1 (images table) looks like this

```
+-----+--------+------+----------------------+-----------+----------+
| id  | nav_id | rang | name                 | img_title | img_text |
+-----+--------+------+----------------------+-----------+----------+
| 700 |     11 |   80 | Siedlg_aussen_26.jpg |           |          |
```

the output I get from the sql statement is:

```
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+----------+------------------+
| img_id | img_nav_id | img_name    | img_title | img_text | nav_id | nav_parent_id | nav_name | nav_directlink   |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------+---------------+----------+------------------+
|    625 |         11 | 07.jpg      | 11        |          |     11 |             3 | Surfabri | surfabricaziun_5 |
|    744 |         20 | 85.jpg      |           |          |     20 |             7 | Test     | test             |
```

now What I want or need is: I need to get the parent nav name. So I would like one more field called nav_parent_name `where t2.parent_id = t2.id` and for this I've tried

```
SELECT 
    t1.id img_id, t1.nav_id img_nav_id, t1.name img_name, t1.img_title img_title, t1.img_text img_text,
    t2.id nav_id,t2.parent_id nav_parent_id, t2.name nav_name, t2.directlink nav_directlink,
    t2.name nav_parent_name
FROM images t1
INNER JOIN navigation t2
INNER JOIN navigation t2
    ON t2.parent_id = t2.id AS nav_parent_name
ON t2.id=t1.nav_id 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,101
```

which isn't working. Problem: I don't know anything about join is it possible to get the result I want or do I have to write a new Sql statement which would be easy but I would love to have only one statement working for all data I need.

Thanks in advance to everyone reading for any suggetions and advices.

Comment: you may want to read about closures tables for handling Hierarchical data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some aliasing problems and need to keep your existing join while adding a new on

```
SELECT 
    t1.id img_id, t1.nav_id img_nav_id, t1.name img_name, t1.img_title img_title, t1.img_text img_text,
    t2.id nav_id,t2.parent_id nav_parent_id, t2.name nav_name, t2.directlink nav_directlink,
    t3.name nav_parent_name
FROM images t1
INNER JOIN navigation t2
  ON t2.id=t1.nav_id
INNER JOIN navigation t3
    ON t2.parent_id = t3.id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,101
```